# MailChimp OAuth2: Invalid Mailchimp API Key - wrong datacenter - library may not support datacenter mapping scheme

Tags: python, django, oauth, mailchimp

I have successfully implemented a one time pass through MailChimp's (MC) six step OAuth2 process, documented at http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/oauth2/, using Python and Django. The problem is I want my users to be able to authorize MC once and then I will use that authorization to make calls to MC in the future (with their permission, of course).

Here's how I am doing it:

**Step 1**: Redirect use to the MC authorize URI.

(works fine)

**Step 2**: User enters their MC credentials.

(works fine)

**Step 3**: User gets redirected back to a URI on my server, and
**Step 4**: I make a request to the MC access token URI, and
**Step 5**: MC returns an access token.

```
headers = {                                                                                 
    'User-Agent': 'oauth2-draft-v10',                                                       
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                                    
    'Host': 'login.mailchimp.com',                                                          
    'Accept': 'application/json'                                                            
}                                                                                           
payload = {                                                                                 
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',                                                     
    'client_id': settings.MAILCHIMP_CLIENT_ID,                                              
    'client_secret': settings.MAILCHIMP_CLIENT_SECRET,                                      
    'code': code,                                                                           
    'redirect_uri': settings.MAILCHIMP_REDIRECT_URI                                         
}                                                                                           

response = requests.post(settings.MAILCHIMP_ACCESS_TOKEN_URI, headers=headers, data=payload)
response_dict = response.json()                                                             
access_token = response_dict['access_token']
```

At this point I save the access_token, the datacenter-less API key, in my database.

**Step 6**: I make a request to the MC metadata URI to get a datacenter.

Note that this step occurs multiple times as I need to make MC calls on the user's behalf, whereas Steps 1-5 only occur once.

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + access_token}                                        
response = requests.get(settings.MAILCHIMP_METADATA_URI, headers=headers)                   
response_dict = response.json()                                                             
dc = response_dict['dc']
```

**Step 7**: I construct an API key and make MC calls using the Python library.

```
mkey = access_token + '-' + dc
mcapi = mailchimp.Mailchimp(apikey=mkey)

mcapi.do_something_fun_with_mailchimp()...
```

The problem is that the final step intermittently returns the error,

> Invalid Mailchimp API Key: `<key>-dc` . You are accessing the wrong datacenter - your client library may not properly support our datacenter mapping scheme.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: key doesnt look like a valid api key token. Did you generate it this way? http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/where-can-i-find-my-api-key/#generating

Comment: It's a full token; I italicized it and replaced it with "key" so I wouldn't expose an actual API key.

Comment: Ah.. ok.. that makes sense.. editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workflow is correct, except that I only need to do it once. I can store the access_token and the datacenter (*key*-*dc*) in my database and use it for future calls.

Although I still don't know exactly what was causing my problem, I now know that it was not related to this workflow. It's correct.

Comment: Update: the problem was that MailChimp's Python library did not allow for workflows that involved making calls with different API keys in the same process (ridiculous). See https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-python-examples/issues/3 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Endpoint in the client library is "http://.api.mailchimp.com" so you need to send the token as only access token as per this part from documentation:

> api_endpoint - this is http://.api.mailchimp.com. If you don't
>   have a datacenter aware wrapper, use this api endpoint and the
>   access_token as your API Key.